# How to find specific HTML element by keyword?

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, dom, beautifulsoup

I'm having problems on how to find a specific HTML element when having a keyword:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="ct-itemProducts ct-u-marginBottom20" >
        <div class="ct-main-content">
        
            <div class="ct-main-text" >
                
                <div class="ct-product--tilte">
                    COMPUTIME
                </div>
```

My keyword is `COMPUTIME` and I want to detect `className` of this div:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with JavaScript:

```
for (const a of document.querySelectorAll(".ct-product--tilte")) {
  if (a.textContent.includes("COMPUTIME")) {
  console.log(a.textContent)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to get element class by searching on the TEXT in your div, then you can try something like this:

```js
var allElement = document.querySelectorAll('*');
var myElement = null;

var valueToSearch = "COMPUTIME"; 

allElement.forEach(el => {
  if(el.innerHTML.trim() === valueToSearch) {
    myElement = el;
  }
})

console.log(myElement) // My element HTML
console.log(myElement.className) // My Class 
console.log(myElement.id) // My id

var parentSearching = true;

while(parentSearching) {
  myElement = myElement.parentElement;
  if (myElement.className.includes('col')) {
    parentSearching = true;
    break;
  }
}

console.log(myElement.className); // col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
  <div class="ct-itemProducts ct-u-marginBottom20" >
    <div class="ct-main-content">
      <div class="ct-main-text" >
        <div class="ct-product--tilte">
          COMPUTIME
        </div>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you but i whant to auto detect that class. [link](https://www.lespagesjaunesafrique.com/societes/maroc/telecommunication-transmission-de-donnees/)  is the page im working on inspect it and you will understand

Comment: Hope my edit will help you and solve  your problem

Comment: thank you for helping but that the problem in my case i dont khnow the class  "col-sm-6 col-md-6 " so i can't  do .includes('col') i whant it t be automaicly detected

Comment: Have you some informations ? he is all time the 4th parente, he all time have class xxx, or maybe another information ? 

Cause we can't help you more in the other case

Comment: that the complexite im speaking of.as input i have "ct-product--tilte" and as output "<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">"